# Subclassing NSCoder, recreating NSArchiver

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, nscoder

`NSArchiver` is deprecated since OS X 10.2, and is not available AFAIK on iOS

On the other hand, `NSKeyedArchiver` is known to be lacking on the speed & conciseness part ([some users](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/145404-nskeyedarchiver-alternatives-for-speed-improvements.html) report more than 100 times performance difference between `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSArchiver`). The objects I want to archive are mainly `NSObject` subclasses containing `NSMutableArray` of `NSNumber`, and objects containing primitive types (mainly `double`). I am not convinced the overhead keyed archiving implies is worth it.

So I decided to subclass `NSCoder` on iOS to create a serial coder, in the style of `NSArchiver`.

I understand where keyed archives might come in handy : backward forward compatibility and other niceties, and it probably is what I will end up using, but I'd be curious to know what kind of performances I could get with serial archiving. And frankly, I think I could learn a lot of things by doing this. So I am *not* interested in an alternative solution;

I've been inspired by the sources of [Cocotron](https://code.google.com/p/cocotron/source/browse/Foundation/NSArchiver.m), providing an open source `NSArchiver`

**TLDR** : I want to subclass `NSCoder` to rebuild `NSArchiver`

---

I am using ARC, compiling for iOS 6 & 7, and assuming 32bit system for now.

I am not interested in referencing objects or strings for now, I am only using a `NSHashTable` (`weakObjectsHashTable`) to prevent classes names to be duplicated : classes will be described the first time they are encountered, and then referred to by reference.

I am using a `NSMutableData` to build the archive :

```
@interface Archiver {
    NSMutableData *_data;
    void *_bytes;
    size_t _position;
    NSHashTable *_classes;
}
@end
```

The basic methods are :

```
-(void)_expandBuffer:(NSUInteger)length
{
    [_data increaseLengthBy:length];
    _bytes = _data.mutableBytes;
}

-(void)_appendBytes:(const void *)data length:(NSUInteger)length
{
    [self _expandBuffer:length];
    memcpy(_bytes+_position, data, length);
    _position += length;
}
```

I am using `_appendBytes:length:` to dump primitive types such as  `int`, `char`, `float`, `double` ... etc. Nothing interesting there.

C-style strings are dumped using this equally uninteresting method :

```
-(void)_appendCString:(const char*)cString
{
    NSUInteger length = strlen(cString);
    [self _appendBytes:cString length:length+1];

}
```

And finally, archiving class information and objects :

```
-(void)_appendReference:(id)reference {
    [self _appendBytes:&reference length:4];
}

-(void)_appendClass:(Class)class
{
    // NSObject class is always represented by nil by convention 
    if (class == [NSObject class]) {
        [self _appendReference:nil];
        return;
    }

    // Append reference to class
    [self _appendReference:class];

    // And append class name if this is the first time it is encountered
    if (![_classes containsObject:class])
    {
        [_classes addObject:class];
        [self _appendCString:[NSStringFromClass(class) cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    }
}

-(void)_appendObject:(const id)object
{
    // References are saved
    // Although we don't handle relationships between objects *yet* (we could do it the exact same way we do for classes)
    // at least it is useful to determine whether object was nil or not
    [self _appendReference:object];

    if (object==nil)
        return;

    [self _appendClass:[object classForCoder]];
    [object encodeWithCoder:self];

}
```

The `encodeWithCoder:` methods of my objects all look like that, nothing fancy :

```
[aCoder encodeValueOfObjCType:@encode(double) at:&_someDoubleMember];
[aCoder encodeObject:_someCustomClassInstanceMember];
[aCoder encodeObject:_someMutableArrayMember];
```

---

Decoding goes pretty much the same way ;
The unarchiver holds a `NSMapTable` of classes it already knows and looks for the name of classes reference it does not know.

```
@interface Unarchiver (){
    NSData *_data;
    const void *_bytes;
    NSMapTable *_classes;
}

@end
```

I won't bore you with the specifics of

```
-(void)_extractBytesTo:(void*)data length:(NSUInteger)length
```

and

```
-(char*)_extractCString
```

The interesting stuff is probably in the object decoding code :

```
-(id)_extractReference
{
    id reference;
    [self _extractBytesTo:&reference length:4];
    return reference;
}


-(Class)_extractClass
{

    // Lookup class reference
    id classReference = [self _extractReference];

    // NSObject is always nil
    if (classReference==nil)
        return [NSObject class];

    // Do we already know that one ?
    if (![_classes objectForKey:classReference])
    {
        // If not, then the name should follow

        char *classCName = [self _extractCString];
        NSString *className = [NSString stringWithCString:classCName encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        free(classCName);

        Class class = NSClassFromString(className);

        [_classes setObject:class forKey:classReference];
    }

    return [_classes objectForKey:classReference];

}

-(id)_extractObject
{
    id objectReference = [self _extractReference];

    if (!objectReference)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    Class objectClass = [self _extractClass];
    id object = [[objectClass alloc] initWithCoder:self];

    return object;

}
```

And finally, the central method (I would not be surprised if the problem is somewhere here)

```
-(void)decodeValueOfObjCType:(const char *)type at:(void *)data
{


    switch(*type){
        /* snip, snip */
        case '@':
            *(id __strong *) data = [self _extractObject];
            break;
    }
}
```

The `initWithCoder:` method corresponding to the previous snippet of `encodeWithCoder:` would go something like that

```
if (self = [super init]) {
    // Order is important
    [aDecoder decodeValueOfObjCType:@encode(double) at:& _someDoubleMember];
    _someCustomClassInstanceMember = [aDecoder decodeObject];
    _someMutableArrayMember = [aDecoder decodeObject]; 
}
return self;
```

My `decodeObject` implementation is exactly `_extractObject`.

Now, all this should work nice and well. And as a matter of fact; I am able to archive/unarchive some of my objects. The archives look fine, to the extent that I am willing to inspect them in an hex editor, and I am able to unarchive some of my custom classes containing `NSMutableArray`s of some other class containing `double`s.

---

But for some reason, if I try to unarchive one of my object containing a `NSMutableArray` of `NSNumber`, I run into this problem :

```
malloc: *** error for object 0xc112cc: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

There seems to be one line per `NSNumber` in the array, and the address `0xc112cc` is the same for every line. Putting a breakpoint in `malloc_error_break` tells me the errors is from `-[NSPlaceholderNumber initWithCoder:]` (called from my `_extractObject` method).

Is that a problem linked to my usage of ARC ? What am I missing ?

Comment: Could you share a minimal initWithCoder: implementation?

Comment: I updated my post with a sample `initWithCoder:` implementation. It is quite straightforward.

Comment: it may have something to do with tag pointer, check is `0xc112cc` the actual value you are archiving?

Comment: Hmm, looks fine. I wonder if this is related to the fact that NSNumber is a class cluster. It also looks like the base class NSValue is the thing that implements coding rather than NSNumber itself.

Comment: (and for a good guide to tagged pointers + NSNumber, see this: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-07-27-lets-build-tagged-pointers.html)

Comment: NSArray is a class cluster as well and I don't seem to have a problem with it. I'm going to look into the tagged pointer thing

Comment: I have just edited my question with additional info, please take a look

Comment: Is that happening for all classes, or just custom ones?

Comment: (note semantics required of init methods here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#semantics-of-init, which effectively means that you must assign `[super init]` to `self` in init family methods (including initWithXYZ methods). It looks like you're correctly doing that though...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My error was linked to a misunderstanding of the second argument of `-(void)encodeValueOfObjCType:(const char *)type at:(const void *)addr` in the case where `type` represents a C-string ( `*type == '*'`). In that case `addr` is a `const char **`, a pointer to the  the `const char *`, which is itself points to the constant, `0` terminated array of `char` that should be encoded.

`NSNumber encodeWithCoder:` encodes a small C-string representing the type of the variable backing the value (an `i` for `int`, `d` for double, etc. it is equal AFAIK to the `@encode` directive).

My previous misinterpretation (assuming `addr` was a `const char *`) made an incorrect encoding/decoding, and the `initWithCoder:` was thus failing (bottom line : it was trying to `free` a stack variable, thus the error message and the fact that the address was always the same for every call of the function).

I now have a working implementation.
If anyone is interested, the code is on my [GitHub](https://github.com/FlorianDenis/Serial-Archiver) under the MIT license.